# Philips Semiconductors SAA7160 tv tuner driver installation help

Tags: 12.10, drivers, tv-tuner, dv6

First of all new to Linux.
Ive been trying to install the driver for my tvtuner on my dv6 intel/nvidia setup
Everytime i try to install the driver I get access denied. So im stumped? Now heres some detail of the driver:

> ```
> Multimedia controller: Philips Semiconductors SAA7160 (rev 03)
> Subsystem: Avermedia Technologies Inc Device 0a55
> Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
> Memory at da100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
> Capabilities: <access denied>
> ```

Also ive downloaded the linux firmware nonfree driver from software centre. Put them into lib/firmware folder. I'm getting quite confused about the command line that i need to get the driver working. Ive learnt alot about linux trying to get this working so it has been a good expirience. I am however stuck here now so even if someone says start looking here thats would help. I did look trhough the tvtuner wiki for linux and theres nothing there for this tuner.

> Heres a joke while I wait for an answer... An Android tablet went up to a Linux pc and said, 'Whats a tablet gotta do to get a ROOT around here!'